# Selenium Java Question, facing issue in fluent wait

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I have updated selenium dependency to 4.1.1
And in fluent wait object i am facing this error.
my object code is:

```
FluentWait wait =new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
  .withTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
```

**Error is this:**

```
java: method withTimeout in class org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.time.Duration
  found: int,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `withTimeout` takes a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) argument. The same goes for `pollingEvery`:

```java
fluentWait wait =
    new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30L))
        .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(5L))
        .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
```

**EDIT:**
FWIW, the usage sample in the `FluentWait` class refers to deprecated methods that no longer exist (IIUC, since 4.0.0). The fact that the sample usage was not updated accordingly is a bug.
I've filed a [bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10207) on the project and issued a [PR](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/10208), which has already been merged, to fix it.